# How to print the pdf or image file through printer in android?

Tags: android, android-view

In my application, I am changing the view to PDF, but I don't know how to print the file using printer.

**My View to PDF Code**

```
//Below layout View is to change PDF 
RelativeLayout MyView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.print);
            try{

                View v1 = MyView.getRootView();
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                bitmap = v1.getDrawingCache();

                if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
                    {  
                        file =new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Test Folder");
                         if(!file.exists())
                        {
                          file.mkdirs();

                         } 
                         //f = new File(file, "filename"+.png);
                         //f= new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+file.separator+"test"+".png");
                        f= new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+file.separator+"test"+".pdf");
                    }
                /*  FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(f);                                   
                  bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
                  ostream.close();*/

                 } 
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Document document=new Document();
            try{

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(f));
                document.open();
                Image image = Image.getInstance (byteArray);
                document.add(new Paragraph(""));
                document.add(image);               
                document.close();


            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This all function I am putting in print button, after I click the print button change relative layout view to PDF , my doubt is after changing to PDF file I want to print that PDF file through printer. I don't have idea about print function.Can any one know please help me to solve this problem?